# SMS Studio : Because of more than 160 characters LIMIT on SMS, I am getting the second message first and then the first message

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

When I am sending the SMS from **SMS studio of marketing cloud** the message is divided into 2 parts because of more than 160 characters LIMIT and I am getting the second message first and then the first message.

So what I can do to get the first message first and the second message is second. I have already selected the concatenate checkbox while configuring SMS.

Please help.

Comment: if you received two messages, the message was not concatenated, does the market you are sending to support concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

This really does sound like something you won't solve without Salesforce Support as we don't have any control over concatenation apart from this checkbox and can't set an order in which the parts would be delivered.

Create a support case and follow the guidelines ([from this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320052&type=1&mode=1)):

> **Minimum Information Needed to Investigate**
>
> - At least 5 mobile numbers experiencing the same issue
> - Sends must have happened no greater than 5 days ago

It's very likely the support agent that gets the case will try to ask for this and refuse to investigate the issue until you provide this data.

We can only speculate what's going on, but one likely cause would be that the integration between Marketing Cloud and the local operator company that is performing the SMS sends is not working properly. Only support agent could work with this other company and use your examples to identify any issues.